# one to many relation ship in java spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, one-to-many

I have 2 tables Users and Institution, with primary keys respectively user_Id and institution_id.
Each user works at one and only one institution, although an institution can have many Users.
so its a one to many relation ship.
But in my mySQL db the institution table has a fixed number of institutions that the user can work in.
there is a foreign key of institution_Id in my user table that specifies which institution does he work for.
while adding the user using a rest api i can't specify which institution does he work for

-----user model-----

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

-------Institution model--------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="institution_Id")
    private int institutionId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> user;
    
}
```

------controller------
here im using api's to add users...

```
@GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return (List<User>) userrepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userrepository.save(user);
        return "user saved with name: " + user.getName();
    }
```

is there a way to do it ?

--------the api request---------

```
{
    "name" : "Jawad",
    "lastname" : "Zakhour",
    "email" : "jawadzakhour@hotmail.com",
    "password" : "jawad123",
    "isActive" : 0,
    "lastActive" : "13/08/2020",
    "createdDate" : "07/07/2020",
    "isBlocked" : 0,
    "institution" : 
        {
            "name" : "maliks",
            "type" : "Merchant",
            "location" : "Le mall sen el fil"
        }
    
}
```

...

Comment: What have you tried so far? While saving a user, have you tried passing the `institutionId` of the institution which the user works for? - Considering Institution is a master data already present in your DB.

Comment: I use postman so yes i tried adding everything in my json body all the fields of user plus the fields of institution, can you please give me an example  please @Sudoss

Comment: @jayee sure I can. Can you please update your question with the JSON body that you are sending through postman? Also, please ensure you have some rows inserted for institution table in your DB.

Comment: yes sure i will update my question and yes there is records in institutions in my db @Sudoss

Comment: Thanks for adding the details, clease check my solution and let us know if you face any issues....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding details.
You can achieve the same by passing the primary key of the `institution` table which is `institution_Id` for the corresponding record.

For Example- If you want the user `Jawad` to be linked to the institution `maliks`, then your `institution` table should have a row inserted already with values as `maliks, Merchant, Le mall sen el fil` for `name`, `type` and `location` columns respectively. (I am assuming this recod has `institution_Id` = 1 in your DB)

Then you need to pass the below JSON as request

```
{
    "name" : "Jawad",
    "lastname" : "Zakhour",
    "email" : "jawadzakhour@hotmail.com",
    "password" : "jawad123",
    "isActive" : 0,
    "lastActive" : "13/08/2020",
    "createdDate" : "07/07/2020",
    "isBlocked" : 0,
    "institution" : 
        {
            "institutionId" : 1  // As per my assumption stated above
        }
    
}
```

Another thing you need to make sure is your `User` model has cascade set like below

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    private Institution institution;
```

Comment: can i ask you one more question?
its about adding a role to a user ...
its a many to many relationship
should i ask a new question or update this one ?
thank you

Comment: It is always better to ask a new question, if you update this question, the answer might look out of context and it would not help the community in any way.

Comment: i asked a new question @Sudoss